# C# Can't Download for some Users

Tags: c#, error-handling, download

I created with C# an App and on Startup it will try to Download a File and Rename it to an exe.
Some Users(most of them are on Windows 7)
Come to Catch and after the Catch they get a Appcrash:

```
Problem signature:
```

Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:    myexe.exe
  Problem Signature 02:    1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:    53532c30
  Problem Signature 04:    myexe
  Problem Signature 05:    1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:    53532c30
  Problem Signature 07:    6
  Problem Signature 08:    66
  Problem Signature 09:    System.ComponentModel.Win32
  OS Version:    6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1:    5861
  Additional Information 2:    5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3:    01d7
  Additional Information 4:    01d7340064827245f2249cd1f1a7c264

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

```
try
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                var credentials = new NetworkCredential("sampleuser", "samplepw");
                webClient.Credentials = credentials;
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://sampleurl/samplefile."),
                    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
                        "aspnet_execute.exe"));
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Timed Out.", "Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Close();
            }
```

Cant seem to find a Fix for that :(.

---

Update:
Fixed it now those where in Test Mode of Windows.

Now i only have a Problem that after the file got downloaded and executed,
the Downloaded Executeable will end in a ".exe has Stopped Working"
if they arnt in compatibility mode.
The download and execute exe is compiled in cpp and does only a while(true) everything else is empty. That Problem is fixed if they enable compatibility mode to win7.

Comment: If it's only some users then it may be something involving security settings. I'd recommend against an empty catch statement and change it to `catch( System.Exception ex )` and then include `ex.Message` in your MessageBox output. That will give you a lot more info as to the specific problem.

Comment: Update: Fixed it now those where in Test Mode of Windows.

Now i only have a Problem that after the file got downloaded and executed, the Downloaded Executeable will end in a ".exe has Stopped Working" if they arnt in compatibility mode. The download and execute exe is compiled in cpp and does only a while(true) everything else is empty. That Problem is fixed if they enable compatibility mode to win7.